# Add a entry (variable) yaml file using sed

Tags: shell, sed, yaml

I have a yaml file (dsn-details.yaml) that looks like this:

```
postgresql:
  Database: postgres
  Servername: server
  Username: user
  Password: pwd
  Port: 5432
```

I want to add new entries under postgresql and want something like this:

```
postgresql:
  version: 13.01
  Database: postgres
  Servername: server
  Username: user
  Password: pwd
  Port: 5432
```

I am able to do the same using following command:

```
connector="postgresql"

sed -r "s/^(\s*${connector}\s*:\s*).*/&\n\  version: 13.01/" -i dsn-details.yaml
```

However, i dont want to hardcode "version: 13.01" part in the above sed command. I want to pass it using a variable as below:

```
versionentry="version: 13.01"
sed -r "s/^(\s*${connector}\s*:\s*).*/&\n\${versionentry}/" -i dsn-details.yaml
```

In this case i am getting error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 45: unknown option to `s'
```

Can anyone help with the exact command

Comment: Could you download and install YAML parsing tool `yq`? https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#install ?

Comment: not able to download yq on debain 10

Comment: You can download the 32-bit or 64-bit binary directly from the releases page - https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.13.4 depending on your CPU arch

Answer (score 1):

Your `sed` command escapes the `$` which it should not if you want to substitute the variable's value. It also misses the indentation.

Here's a working version:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
connector="postgresql"
versionentry="version: 13.01"
sed -r "s/^(\s*${connector}\s*:\s*).*/&\n  ${versionentry}/" <<'EOF'
postgresql:
  Database: postgres
  Servername: server
  Username: user
  Password: pwd
  Port: 5432
EOF
```